# How to check and return a boolean with Javascript if a certain key has a certain value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

I have an array of objects in my Javascript/React app:

```
[
 {type: 'TypeOne'} 
 {type: 'TypeFive'}
 {type: 'TypeTen'}
]
```

How to return a boolean `true` if the array contains an object with key/value `type: 'TypeTen'`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some    ->  `array.some(f => f.type === 'TypeTen')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two ways to do this:

1. The trivial way (using the syntactical features of JavaScript)
2. The better way (using Array methods to solve your issue)

### 1. The Trivial Way

This way can be clearer and allow beginners to read your code easily. It's also cleaner and slightly more efficient:

```js
const source = [ { 'type': 'TypeOne' }, ... ]
for (const obj of source)
    if (obj.type == 'TypeTen')
        return true
return false
```

### 2. The better way

This way is better (in my opinion) because of brevity. It's a one-liner and still easy enough to read and understand. It will be slightly less efficient in larger arrays since it has to invoke a callback `arr.length` times.

```js
arr.some(obj => obj.type == 'TypeTen')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.prototype.some() method along with an arrow function. Here's an example:

```
function checkTypeExists(targetType) {
    return arr.some(obj => obj.type === targetType);
}
```